# Can I schedule PayPal payment gateway process for 30 days after the client registration?

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

Is there any possiblities to schedule paypal payment gateway process after completion of 30 days trial period? And one thing is, that the user need to enter all payment credentials on registration.is this possible?

**Flow of process**
user **->** *entering payment details* **->** *30 days of trails*(in this trials user can cancel membership) **->** *payment gateway process start automatically*(after completing 30 days of trial) by using user credentials **->** user continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For setting up your scenario you can refer this documentation

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-freeTrialRecurringPayments-curl-etc/

Comment: Thanks @user3020426. This doc is very useful to proceed with my work.